# ADO.net Adding columns to entity outside DB

Tags: wcf, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I had a hard time to come up with a title for this :)

I've got a WCF service hooked up to a SQL-server database. I retrieve data from the DB using ADO.NET.

On some simple operations I just retrieve from the DB and then send back a json representation of the EntityObjects i just fetched which works fine. However now I'm doing a more complex fetch with a procedure. The data retrieval works fine but the procdure itself returns more columns than the actual EntityObject (Table) has. Take this for an example:

```
create table Person
{
    Name,
    BirthDate
}

// Retrieve Persons from DB with procedure that also calculates each persons actual age!
public List<EntityObject> GetPersons()
{
    var personList = new List<EntityObject>();
    var dataSet = dbContext.ExceuteProcedure("GET_PERSONS_WITH_AGE", parameters);

    var dataTable = dataSet.Tables["result"];

    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        personList.Add( new PersonEntity
        {
            Name = (String)row["Name"],
            BirthDate = (DateTime)row["BirthDate"],
            // Here i want the actual age calculation result, but since the DB-table Person does'nt have this column,
            // I can't set it.
        }
    }

    return personList;
}
```

Do I need to create a CustomPersonClass for this which has this extra variable? Or can I somehow force another column into Table Person in my ADO.NET object?

Please consider that I'm novice about ADO.NET, if you see other code faults in my example (regarding methods of retrival as well) please let me know.

Comment: Are you using the Entity Framework ORM and generating your model, are you using Code First?

Comment: I'm generating my model with a .edmx object, don't know if that is ORM. What is Code First?

Comment: Code First is an Entity Framework feature where you can write your model/database in C# and have it generate all your tables/stored procedures. You don't design your database using Sql Server Management Studio. It is nice because your code all lives in one place and you define all structure and even validation in one place, your project/solution. It requires learning a new set of skills, syntax and new concepts though and I have found to me more trouble than it is worth and gets too complicated enforcing foreign key and composite key relationships compared to just making my database ol fashion

Comment: Thank you very much taking time to explain that. I think I will go for a old fashioned solution here but when I have time I might look into Code First!

Answer (score 1):

You may consider a DTO here, a data transfer object, this addresses the considerations of the caller/client of getPersons and will be generated as JSON back to the client.  Call it PersonDTO or PersonResponse. It lives in the same class as the getPersons() method and is a public class. Change the signature to of getPersons() to `List<PersonDTO> getPersons()`. I would also captialize GetPersons() as it is a public method.

```
public class PersonDTO
{
    property string Name;
    property string BirthDate;
    property string Age;
}

// Retrieve Persons from DB with procedure that also calculates each persons actual age!
public List<PersonDTO> getPersons()
{
    var personList = new List<PersonDTO>();
    var dataSet = dbContext.ExceuteProcedure("GET_PERSONS_WITH_AGE", parameters);

var dataTable = dataSet.Tables["result"];

foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    personList.Add( new PersonDTO
    {
        Name = (String)row["Name"],
        BirthDate = (DateTime)row["BirthDate"],
        // Here i want the actual age calculation result, but since the DB-table Person does'nt have this column,
        // I can't set it.
    }
}

return personList;
}
```

Comment: I suspected this. Just wanted to ask in case there was any other options since I might be required to create a lot of these DTO:classes in the future. About the syntax, I'm too used to Java :)